# How do I melt a pandas with custom nam

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, melt, pandas-melt

I have a table like this

| device_type | version | pool | testMean | testP50 | testP90 | testP99 | testStd | WidgetMean | WidgetP50 | WidgetP90 | WidgetP99 | WidgetStd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PNB0Q7 | 8108162 | 123 | 124 | 136 | 140.8 | 141.88 | 21.35 | 2.2 | 0 | 6.4 | 9.64 | 3.92 |

I want it to be transformed like this:

| device_type | version | pool | Name | Mean | P50 | P90 | P99 | Std |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PNB0Q7 | 8108162 | 123 | test | 123 | 136 | 140.8 | 142.88 | 21.35 |
| PNB0Q7 | 8108162 | 123 | Widget | 2.2 | 0 | 6.4 | 9.64 | 3.92 |

I tried using melt but getting:

```
df.melt(id_vars=["device_type", "version", "pool"], var_name="Name", value_name="Value")
```

| device_type | version | pool | Name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PNB0Q7 | 8108162 | test | testMean | 124.00 |
| PNB0Q7 | 8108162 | test | testP50 | 136.00 |
| PNB0Q7 | 8108162 | test | testP90 | 140.80 |
| PNB0Q7 | 8108162 | test | testP99 | 141.88 |
| PNB0Q7 | 8108162 | test | testStd | 21.35 |

Any idea on how to reach to expected solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `pd.wide_to_long` and a little column naming cleanup first, then reshape:

```
df = df.rename(columns={'Std':'testStd',
                        'TestP90':'testP90',
                        'TestP99':'testP99', 
                        'TestP50':'testP50'})
df_out = pd.wide_to_long(df, 
                         ['test','Widget'], 
                         ['device_type', 'version', 'pool'], 
                         'Measure', '', '.+' )
df_out = df_out.unstack(-1).stack(0).reset_index()
df_out
```

Output:

```
Measure device_type  version  pool level_3   Mean    P50    P90     P99    Std
0            PNB0Q7  8108162   123  Widget    2.2    0.0    6.4    9.64   3.92
1            PNB0Q7  8108162   123    test  124.0  136.0  140.8  141.88  21.35
```

Update renaming 'level_3' above:

```
df = df.rename(columns={'Std':'testStd',
                        'TestP90':'testP90',
                        'TestP99':'testP99', 
                        'TestP50':'testP50'})
df_out = pd.wide_to_long(df, 
                         ['test','Widget'], 
                         ['device_type', 'version', 'pool'], 
                         'Measure', '', '.+' )\
            .rename_axis('Instrument', axis=1) #add this line to rename column header axis
df_out = df_out.unstack(-1).stack(0).reset_index()
df_out
```

Output:

```
Measure device_type  version  pool Instrument   Mean    P50    P90     P99    Std
0            PNB0Q7  8108162   123     Widget    2.2    0.0    6.4    9.64   3.92
1            PNB0Q7  8108162   123       test  124.0  136.0  140.8  141.88  21.35
```

Comment: `pd.wide_to_long` is good for situation where you need to do simultaneous melting on columns.

Comment: I'd suggest flipping the columns, so test/widget is at the end, and then run wide_to_long, that way you do not need the stack/unstack combination, which only makes the process more expensive (current steps does a wide to long to wide to long, three steps)

Comment: I am getting exception with large data
  File "/Users/jaiadi/Desktop/PostProcessAnalysisFile.py", line 29, in <module>
    df_out = df_out.unstack(-1).stack(0).reset_index()
    return _Unstacker(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/reshape.py", line 120, in __init__
    self._make_selectors()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/reshape.py", line 169, in _make_selectors
    raise ValueError("Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape")
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Comment: With duplicate entries you are going to have to uses groupby and aggregate like values with sum, mean, first or some sort of aggregation function.

Comment: Can we rename the column name also e.g. level_3 in above example

Comment: @Aditya See update.

Answer (score 1):

```
df.columns = ['device_type', 'version', 'pool', 'Mean', 'P50', 'P90', 'P99', 'Std']
df['Name'] = 'test'
df = df[['device_type', 'version', 'pool', 'Name', 'Mean', 'P50', 'P90', 'P99', 'Std']]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  device_type  version  pool  Name  Mean  P50    P90     P99    Std
0      PNB0Q7  8108162   123  test   124  136  140.8  141.88  21.35
```

Comment: Is there a way if i have multiple entry? How to put multiple names?


device_type version pool testMean TestP50 TestP90 TestP99 Std   WidgetMean WidgetP50 WidgetP90 WidgetP99 WidgetStd
PNB0Q7     8108162 123  124         136     140.8 141.88 21.35  2.2   0   6.4   9.64  3.92

Comment: Editing the full version of whatever it is you want to do into your question sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to transform to long form with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), using the `.value` placeholder ---> the `.value` determines which parts of the columns remain as headers. First we need to ensure that `Test` is lowercase:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('Test', 'test')

df

  device_type  version  pool  testMean  testP50  testP90  testP99    Std
0      PNB0Q7  8108162   123       124      136    140.8   141.88  21.35

df.pivot_longer(
     column_names = 'test*', 
     names_to = ('Name', '.value'), 
    names_pattern = r"(test)(.+)"
   )

  device_type  version  pool    Std  Name  Mean  P50    P90     P99
0      PNB0Q7  8108162   123  21.35  test   124  136  140.8  141.88
```

With the updated data, the same concept applies; however, you need to arrange your columns properly - get the `Test` as lowercase, change `Std` to `testStd`:

```py
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('Test', 'test')
df = df.rename(columns = {'Std': 'testStd'})
df

  device_type  version  pool  testMean  testP50  testP90  testP99  testStd  WidgetMean  WidgetP50  WidgetP90  WidgetP99  WidgetStd
0      PNB0Q7  8108162   123       124      136    140.8   141.88    21.35         2.2          0        6.4       9.64       3.92

df.pivot_longer(
     column_names = ['test*', 'Widget*'], 
     names_to = ('Name', '.value'), 
     names_pattern = r"(test|Widget)(.+)"
    )

  device_type  version  pool    Name   Mean  P50    P90     P99    Std
0      PNB0Q7  8108162   123    test  124.0  136  140.8  141.88  21.35
1      PNB0Q7  8108162   123  Widget    2.2    0    6.4    9.64   3.92
```

Comment: Is there a way if i have multiple entry? How to put multiple column names? 
e.g.

device_type version pool testMean TestP50 TestP90 TestP99 Std WidgetMean WidgetP50 WidgetP90 WidgetP99 WidgetStd PNB0Q7 8108162 123 124 136 140.8 141.88 21.35 2.2 0 6.4 9.64 3.92